# ImportError: cannot import name 'sync_playwright' from 'playwright.async_api'

Tags: python, python-3.x, playwright, playwright-python

I initially did

```
pip3 install playwright
playwright install
```

Then tried uninstalling and reinstalling `pip3 install pytest-playwright`. I looked at other StackOverflow questions and none of them worked for me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/userinterview-python/userinterview.py", line 1, in <module>
    from playwright.async_api import sync_playwright, Playwright
ImportError: cannot import name 'sync_playwright' from 'playwright.async_api' (/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/playwright/async_api/__init__.py)
```

---

```
from playwright.async_api import sync_playwright, Playwright

with sync_playwright as p:
  browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=50)
  page = browser.new_page()
  page.goto('google.com')
```

Comment: `from playwright.async_api import sync_playwright`. You're importing sync from the async API. Try importing sync from the sync API (`from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright`).

Comment: Also fix your code in line 3. It should be: `with sync_playwright() as p:` instead of just `sync_playwright` without the parentheses.

Comment: You also forgot to add "https://" in the website url.